# Fundamental Theorem of Calc with epsilon inside

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate the limit:

$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon f(x,\epsilon) dx$$
as $\epsilon \to 0$. Here $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. If $f$ wasn't dependent on $\epsilon$ the answer would just be $f(0)$. Am I correct in assuming that for this case the answer will be $f(0,0)$? If not, what is the expression I am after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon f(x,\epsilon)dx-f(0,0)\\
=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon f(x,\epsilon)dx-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon f(0,0)dx\\
=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon(f(x,\epsilon)-f(0,0))dx$$

Since $f$ is continuous, it is continous at $(0,0)$. Therefore for any $\delta>0$, there exists $\delta'>0$ such that whenever $|(x,y)-(0,0)|<\delta'$, we have $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|<\delta$.

As long as $|\epsilon|<\delta'/\sqrt2$, we can estimate the integral:

$$\left|\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon f(x,\epsilon)dx-f(0,0)\right|\\
\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon|f(x,\epsilon)-f(0,0)|dx\\
\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon\delta dx=\delta$$

Hence $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon f(x,\epsilon)dx=f(0,0)$$

Comment: This is great, but just a small comment: this only uses continuity at $(0,0)$, no need for stronger assumptions or to mention uniform continuity.

Comment: @Raoul Ah...you are right. Perhaps it's because uniform continuity is used too frequently in estimating integrals, and I used it without realizing it is not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

If you let $\int f(x,\varepsilon) dx=F(x,\varepsilon)$, then your definite integral is

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{F(0+\varepsilon,\varepsilon)-F(0,\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}$$

which should remind you what a derivative looks like.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: No, you can't just remove $F(0,\varepsilon)$ like that. As an example to convince you, consider what happens if $F(x,y)=p(x)q(y)$ (i.e. the separable case).

Comment: I used an *antiderivative* and not a definite integral on purpose.

Comment: Sorry, but if you want to definean antiderivative, it is with respect to a certain variable, and you have to say here if it is with respect to the first ($x$) or the second ($\epsilon$). Therefore $F(x,\varepsilon)$ hasn't existence as you wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

Option

MVT for integrals:

$1/\epsilon \displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\epsilon}}f(x,\epsilon)dx=$

$(1/\epsilon)f(t,\epsilon)\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\epsilon}}1dx= f(t,\epsilon)$, where $t \in [0,\epsilon].$

Note : $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} t =0;$

Since $f$ is continuos $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}f(t,\epsilon)=f(0,0).$